# How to call Google Cloud Endpoints RPC API on localhost?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

**EDIT** I posted an issue on this and it should be fixed in release 1.9.16 of Google AppEngine SDK.
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11414

---

I am developing a service using Google Cloud Endpoints.

Both the REST and the RPC API works great when I deploy it on App Engine. However the strange thing is, when I test the service locally (localhost), the REST calls works fine, but I am having trouble with calls using RPC.

My method signature in the backend is:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "user.updateprofile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public UserProfileDto updateProfile(@Named("sessionToken") String sessionToken, UserProfileDto profile) throws UnauthorizedException { return profile; }
```

For simplicity I am just returning the `UserProfileDto` directly.

I have tried to execute the following request locally:

```
POST http://localhost:4567/_ah/api/rpc?prettyPrint=false
Content-Type: application/json-rpc
Accept: application/json-rpc
{
"method": "mobilebackend.user.updateprofile",
"id": "gtl_1",
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"params": {
    "sessionToken": "12345",
    "resource": {
      "username": "foo",
      "userPrivate": true
    }
},
"apiVersion": "v1"
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in the `updateProfile` method, I see that the `sessionToken` is correctly `12345` however the `username` field is `null` and the `userPrivate` field is `false` even though I specified it as `true`. The instance of `UserProfileDto (profile)` is not `null`.

**The problem is** that it fails to inject the values into the fields of the DTO when using RPC calls localhost. When I test it on the deployed version it works fine, and when I use REST calls it works both on localhost and when deployed on App Engine.

When I change the url in the above request to target the deployed version of my application on app engine it works just fine. `https://<app-name>.appspot.com/_ah/api/rpc?prettyPrint=false`

I start the service on localhost using:

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

Do I miss some configuration in order to call the Cloud Endpoints RPC methods localhost? Or is it not supported?

I should notice that I have also tried with the auto-generated iOS client library which is using RPC and it also fails with the same error as the service fails to inject the values into the fields of the DTO object.

Comment: I had the same problem, localhost would continue to give me NULL results for the passed params. Found something in my notes for solving some localhost problems, running the local devserver from the appengine sdk with parameter

 appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6/bin/dev_appserver.sh --address="0.0.0.0"

this solved some of my localhost issues a while ago. Don't remember if this NULL-passing was one of them, this is maybe worth trying?

Comment: @Pega88 Thanks, I will try to start the development server with 0.0.0.0 and see if that fixes the problem. Did you see: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11414 Google states that it should be fixed in release 1.9.16. Which is next release, since 1.9.15 was released for a couple of days ago. They release almost every month, so I am looking forward to get the next release as a christmas present. ;)

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @MarCialR - Hi. Not yet but, I can see that there came a new release 1.9.17 for some days ago. I was promised a fix in 1.9.16, so between christmas and new year when I get time for it, I will check it out and turn back to you. If I forget before new year, post another comment as a reminder. :)

Comment: @dynamokaj have you been able to try 1.9.17?

Comment: @MarCialR Sorry for the late response, I am now using the REST API instead. However I have just tested RPC in the 1.9.17 release and it works fine on localhost now.

Comment: @dynamokaj No prob. Glad to hear your issue has been solved. Maybe you could add an answer or edit your question to make this clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested release 1.9.17 of Google AppEngine SDK and can confirm that using objects in RPC POST requests now works fine.